# c++ Danish chars in filepath

Tags: c++

Im trying to open a file, which all goes well untill I have path with Danish charachters.
the filepath that is contructed is : "Test-0-ØHM/003.jpg"

```
string path = fileSystemPrefix + imagePath;
const char *pstr = path.c_str();
FILE *im = fopen( pstr, "rb" );
```

the path that it tries to open is :
Test-0-Ã˜HM/003.jpg

Platform / Compiler  : Visual Studio 2010 - Visual C++ 10.0

OS : Windows

Could someone point me in the right direction how to open these kind of filepaths ?

Comment: Platform, OS, compiler?

Comment: OT: `FILE *im = fopen`is C, use std::fstream.

Comment: You have to check which encoding you use: utf-8, utf-16, Ansi... and do appropriate code page conversion if necessary.

Comment: _"all goes well untill I have path with Danish charachters"_ and then what happens? Does it stop going well? In what way?

Comment: Is it a console application?

Comment: The string was encoded in utf8 for some unfathomable reason.  If you don't show where it came from then it is just a blind guess.

Comment: If you inspect `pstr` with the debugger right before `fopen`, what does it show? And _how_ is that path constructed?

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the answers.
the  "imagepath" is a string which is has  a value read from a URL. I'm posting the value "Test-0-ØHM/003.jpg" and it turns to "Test-0-Ã˜HM/003.jpg"  I don't do any conversion but according your suggestions I should?

Comment: Is your program compiled with UNICODE or MSBC?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: That doesn't make a difference. `std::string` is always going to be ANSI encoded, unless the source character set has been explicitly changed (e.g. by saving the file as UTF-8 or UTF-16). Nothing of that has anything to do with the compiler environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you do C++ so you need `std::ifstream` in `#include <fstream>`. Then you may need UTF-8 encoding for Danish characters. And Instead of `std::string` you should use `std::wstring`.

Here is a example:

```
std::string StrToUTF8(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    if (wstr.empty()) return std::string();

    /* Maps a UTF-16 (wide character) string to a new character string */
    /* The new character string is not necessarily from a multibyte character set */

    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string strTo(size_needed, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &strTo[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
    return strTo;
}
```

The main problem is commond prompt enviroment. That cannot print out some characters. Do output the result in the file text or html.

Your side (Tested in Visual Studio):

```
std::wstring path = L"C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\WhateverWeirdName.txt";
std::string FileData = "";

const wchar_t *pstr = path.c_str();

std::ifstream inputFile(path);
if (inputFile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(inputFile, FileData))
    {
        std::cout << FileData << "\n";
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi Ali,
Thank you for your answer. I implemented the function and it seems to change the path : "Test-0-ï¿ƒï¾˜HM/003.jpg" instead of Test-0-Ã˜HM/003.jpg. I also changed to an ifstream as you suggested. unfortunately it still cannot find the path.

Comment: @DaanJ I edited my post, See code without converting to UTF-8

Comment: None of the [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) c'tors take a `std::wstring`. This code does not compile. As for the conversion from UTF-16 to UTF-8, this doesn't help at all. The OP already has a UTF-8 encoded string.

Comment: @IInspectable I compiled and tested it in Visual Studio and perfectly works.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:c++]. That precludes use of compiler-specific extensions. In fact, I compiled it in Visual Studio as well, and Clang didn't compile the code.